# can we merge two fragment containers?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity which has layout like this:
[image]

It has two containers in which I can add/replace two fragments.

Now consider a button in second fragment. When user clicks it, two containers should be merged into one container and third fragment C is added to it. like this:[image]

without taking another activity, is it possible or not? Can anyone help please?

Comment: As Lazy Ninja .... suggested ........ Hide and show is the best way to achieve this ! ... make sure you avoid nested fragments as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this kind of situation like this:

```
activity--> 1 container (place here all the fragments)
```

When I need something that would require to have 2 containers, I just create a new Fragment that hosts 2 containers and deal with nested fragments, like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is to have the container C in your layout and set its visibility to View.GONE when you are showing Fragment A and B.
And when showing Fragment C, set Container C visibility to  View.VISIBLE and Container A and B visibility to View.GONE.